# attempting to use incompatible return type

Tags: java, android, admob

Can someone help me with this error that I keep getting? The program that I'm trying to implement admob banner ad between items in recyclerview. every thing is ok but still this one error that blocked me from go on.

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.ViewHolder> {   
    public static final String TAG = RecipeAdapter.class.getSimpleName();   
    public static final HashMap<String, Integer> LABEL_COLORS = new HashMap<String, Integer>()   {{
        put("Low-Carb", R.color.colorLowCarb);
        put("Low-Fat", R.color.colorLowFat);
        put("Low-Sodium", R.color.colorLowSodium);
        put("Medium-Carb", R.color.colorMediumCarb);
        put("Vegetarian", R.color.colorVegetarian);
        put("Balanced", R.color.colorBalanced); 
        }};

  private Context mContext;   
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
  private ArrayList<Recipe> mDataSource;   
  private static final int DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE = 1;   
  private static final int NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 2;

  public RecipeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipe> items) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataSource = items;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   }

  @Override   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Change the position of the ad displayed here. Current is after 5
    if ((position + 1) % 6 == 0) {
      return NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE;   }

  @NonNull


  @Override   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    switch (viewType) {
      default:
        view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_native_ad, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
      case NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_native_ad, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderAdMob(view);
    }

  }

  @Override   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get relevant subviews of row view
    TextView titleTextView = holder.titleTextView;
    TextView subtitleTextView = holder.subtitleTextView;
    TextView detailTextView = holder.detailTextView;
    ImageView thumbnailImageView = holder.thumbnailImageView;


    //Get corresponding recipe for row   final   Recipe recipe = (Recipe) getItem(position);

    // Update row view's textviews to display recipe information
    titleTextView.setText(recipe.title);
    subtitleTextView.setText(recipe.description);
    detailTextView.setText(recipe.label);

    // Use Picasso to load the image. Temporarily have a placeholder in case it's slow to load
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(recipe.imageUrl).placeholder(R.mipmap
            .ic_launcher).into(thumbnailImageView);


    holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {


    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(mContext, RecipeDetailActivity.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra("title", recipe.title);
    detailIntent.putExtra("url", recipe.instructionUrl);

    mContext.startActivity(detailIntent);

      }
    });

    // Style text views
    Typeface titleTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
            "fonts/JosefinSans-Bold.ttf");
    titleTextView.setTypeface(titleTypeFace);
    Typeface subtitleTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
            "fonts/JosefinSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf");
    subtitleTextView.setTypeface(subtitleTypeFace);
    Typeface detailTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Quicksand-Bold.otf");
    detailTextView.setTypeface(detailTypeFace);
    detailTextView.setTextColor(android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, LABEL_COLORS
            .get(recipe.label)));

  }


  @Override   public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();   }


  @Override   public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;   }


  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDataSource.get(position);   }


  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private TextView subtitleTextView;
    private TextView detailTextView;
    private ImageView thumbnailImageView; private View parentView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view){
      super(view);
      // create a new "Holder" with subviews
      this.parentView = view;
      this.thumbnailImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_thumbnail);
      this.titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_title);
      this.subtitleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_subtitle);
      this.detailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_detail);

      // hang onto this holder for future recyclage
      view.setTag(this);
    }

  }

  public class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final AdView mNativeAd;

    public ViewHolderAdMob(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      mNativeAd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nativeAd);
      mNativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
          super.onAdLoaded();
          // if (mItemClickListener != null) {
          Log.i("AndroidBash", "onAdLoaded");
          // }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
          super.onAdClosed();
          //   if (mItemClickListener != null) {
          Log.i("AndroidBash", "onAdClosed");
          //  }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
          super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
          //  if (mItemClickListener != null) {
          Log.i("AndroidBash", "onAdFailedToLoad");
          //  }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
          super.onAdLeftApplication();
          //  if (mItemClickListener != null) {
          Log.i("AndroidBash", "onAdLeftApplication");
          //   }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
          super.onAdOpened();
          //  if (mItemClickListener != null) {
          Log.i("AndroidBash", "onAdOpened");
          //  }
        }
      });
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice("") // Remove this before publishing app
              .build();
      mNativeAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code and errors here directly as text.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5e4Jv7

Comment: Read [mcve] and [ask] for some tips about how to improve  your question if you still need help.

Answer (score 2):

The return type needs to be whatever `ViewHolder` type you declared for your adapter class.

For example, from the Android RecyclerView [example page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
                                //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                //  It should return this type ^

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // your adapter
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        // Note: returns MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, not RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    }
}
```

In your case, you have

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

which means your `onCreateViewHolder` has to return `RecipeAdapter.ViewHolder` not `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

There is a separate issue too, which is that you have two `ViewHolder` types in the same adapter. To do this, you would need to change the `ViewHolder` type that your `RecyclerView` is based on to the generic type (`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`).

Please review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type), it has good answers for how to do this.

Comment: Read my answer, see how to apply it to your code, and if you are unable to do so edit your question to include you entire adapter code - as text, not an image.

Comment: here is the code in clear way i cant post it clear here in stackoverflow they refuse..here is it https://codeshare.io/5e4Jv7

Comment: I updated the answer with your specific case. You have to find `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<STUFF>` in your code and have that function return `STUFF`

Comment: Yes... read my answer and see the linked question for how to use two different ViewHolder types in the same adapter.

Comment: brother i am not a developer my knowledge is limited if you can really help me with this I'll appreciate it

Comment: StackOverflow is not intended to be a place for getting a general coding tutorial or having someone else write your app, it's for specific coding questions. I'd suggest working through some online tutorials or classes on Android development and spending a *lot* of time trying things yourself to learn development.